# custom post type plugin - single template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I'm writing a plugin that creates a cpt.

I can include a template for viewing a single instance of the cpt using the `single_template` filter. And have it look for a template overload in the theme.

```
function my_cpt_single_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'cpt' ) {

        $theme_template = locate_template('single-cpt.php');

        if( file_exists( $theme_template ) )
           $single_template = $theme_template;
        else
           $single_template = PLUGIN_DIR . '/templates/single-cpt.php';

    }

    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'mp_cpt_single_template' );
```

But this loads a template that doesn't take into account whatever the theme might be doing in single.php

So is there a way to just inject part of the current single-cpt.php into the theme's single.php? 
In a way that the template part is overloadable from the theme?

Filtering on `the_content` means the markup is hard-coded into the filter function, yes?
So users would have to hack that function rather than overload the template part and adjust as necessary,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theme templates are inherently not engineered to play well with plugins. As far as I remember there is still no clean and neat solution to shipping template in a plugin and have arbitrary theme pick it up.

There are some libraries, such as [Gamajo Template Loader](https://github.com/GaryJones/Gamajo-Template-Loader), that implement shipping templates in the plugin and allowing to override them. But as far as I understand you will still need to take care of calling template (part) in theme somewhere.

Comment: I've looked at Gamajo and pippin's article about it. It seems that cpts aren't well supported.